# No funcionan el css para hacerse responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, mediaqueries

encontré una página de home muy interesant y la estoy intentando de hacer responsive porque es su único problema. Pero por alguna razón no funcionan los @media. ¿Alguien tiene idea? He revidado todo y creo que está bien. No entiendo que puede estar pasando, no me salen ni en el inspector de elementos. Simplemente puse al final:

> @media only screen and (la distancia a la que quería que actuase) { el contenedor{ lo que quería que hiciera} }

¿Pueden ser por el javascript? ¿O simplemente algún error de código.
Gracias de antemano:
Fdo.: Una novata en css

```js
const wheelEventName = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "wheel" : "mousewheel";
const layers = [...document.querySelectorAll('.layer')];
const tracker = document.querySelector('.track-active');
const trackerNumber = document.querySelector('.track-number');
let itemDisplayed = 0;
let animationPlaying = false;

function resetClasses() {
  for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    layers[0].children[i].classList.remove('item-displayed');
    layers[1].children[i * 2].classList.remove('item-displayed');
  }
}

document.addEventListener(wheelEventName, event => {
  if(!animationPlaying) {
   const nextItem = itemDisplayed + Math.sign(event.deltaY);
    if(nextItem >= 0 && nextItem <= 3) {
      itemDisplayed += Math.sign(event.deltaY);
      layers[0].style = `transform: translateX(${-itemDisplayed * 85}vw);`;
      layers[1].style = `transform: translateX(${- itemDisplayed * 85 * 2}vw);`;
    layers[1].children[itemDisplayed * 2].classList.add('item-revealed');
      
      resetClasses();
    layers[0].children[itemDisplayed].classList.add('item-displayed');
      layers[1].children[itemDisplayed * 2].classList.add('item-displayed');
      
      tracker.style = `transform: translateX(${itemDisplayed * 100}%);`;
      trackerNumber.innerText = `0${itemDisplayed + 1}`;
      setTimeout(() => {
        animationPlaying = false;
      }, 2200);
      animationPlaying = true;
    } 
  }
});
```

```css
:root * {
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  transition: all 2.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.1, 1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 80px;
}
main header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 80px;
  font-size: 28px;
}
main header menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
main header menu a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
main .hero {
  grid-row: 2;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
main .hero .layer {
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 4fr;
  height: 100%;
  transition-duration: 2.2s;
}
main .hero .layer:nth-child(2) .item {
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 4fr;
}
main .hero .layer:nth-child(2) .item h2 {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  font-size: 56px;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  align-self: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translatex(20%);
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
main .hero .layer:nth-child(2) .item svg {
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  grid-column: 2;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  letter-spacing: 12px;
}
main .hero .layer:nth-child(2) .item svg text {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation: anim_rotate 10s linear infinite;
}
main .hero .layer:nth-child(2) .item .text-vertical {
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  grid-column: -2;
  font-size: 56px;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  color: #fc8567;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
}
main .hero .layer:nth-child(2) .item .text-flaveur {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 3;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
main .hero .layer:first-child .item *:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(60%);
}
main .hero .layer:first-child .item *:last-child {
  transform: translateX(-40%);
}
main .hero .layer:first-child .item.item-displayed *:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
main .hero .layer:first-child .item.item-displayed *:last-child {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
main .hero .layer:last-child .item *:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(60%);
}
main .hero .layer:last-child .item *:last-child {
  transform: translateX(500%);
}
main .hero .layer:last-child .item.item-displayed *:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
main .hero .layer:last-child .item.item-displayed *:last-child {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
main .hero .layer:last-child .item.item-revealed h2 {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
main .hero .item {
  grid-row: 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr 1fr 40px;
  grid-gap: 5%;
  width: 85vw;
  padding-left: 80px;
}
main .hero .item img {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
main .hero .item img:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  align-self: end;
}
main .hero .item img:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 100%;
  align-self: end;
  transform: translateY(-30%);
}
main .hero .item img:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 100%;
  align-self: start;
}
main .slider {
  grid-row: -2;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 40px;
  grid-gap: 1%;
  padding: 20px 80px;
}
main .slider .track-full {
  position: relative;
  height: 50%;
  align-self: end;
  border-top: 1px solid #555;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
main .slider .track-active {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  transition-duration: 2.2s;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
main .slider .track-number {
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
main .slider .track-number:after {
  content: "/04";
}
main .background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2.5fr 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1.27fr 1.73fr;
  z-index: -1;
}
main .background-border-horizontal {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
main .background-border-vertical {
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  grid-column: 2;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}

@keyframes anim_rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 10px) and (max-width: 620px){
main .hero .layer:nth-child(2) .item svg{
  font-weight: 800!important;
  font-size: 20px!important;
}
svg main .hero .layer:nth-child(2) .item .text-flaveur {
  font-weight: 400!important;
  font-size: 35px!important;
}

main .hero .item img:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 170%!important;
  max-width: 170%!important;
  align-self: end!important;
}
main .hero .item img:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 210%!important;
  align-self: start!important;
  text-align: left!important;
}
main .hero .item img:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 200%!important;
  align-self: end!important;
}
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="background">
        <div class="background-border-horizontal"></div>
        <div class="background-border-vertical"></div>
      </div>
      <header>
        <span>JUICE.</span>
        <menu>
          <a href="">HOME</a>
          <a href="">ABOUT</a>
          <a href="">CONTACT</a>
          <a href="">SHOP</a>
        </menu>
      </header>
      <section class="hero">
        <div class="layer">
          <div class="item item-displayed">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543363950-725dc7180660?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=701&q=80">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1487630635739-af858c5981e2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1478125025470-6faaedf10a6f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=678&q=80">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543364038-28b7a0578c18?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543363136-314062964bef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1539685524231-a8788edad4e4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=729&q=80">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543363136-1f7a5dfbc219?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517816428104-797678c7cf0c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541795795328-f073b763494e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542021786561-540d84b3f1b2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543363136-9b070a911153?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543322172-ca61a90b780c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="layer">
          <div class="item item-revealed item-displayed">
            <h2>RED ACTIVITY.</h2>
            <svg>
              <path id="curve" fill="transparent" d="M 75 75 m -50, 0 a 50, 50 0 1, 1 100, 0 a 50, 50 0 1, 1 -100, 0"/>
              <text textLength="310">
                <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
                  *ORGANIC*PRODUCT
                </textPath>
              </text>
            </svg>
            <span class="text-vertical">ORGANIC</span>
            <span class="text-flaveur">Nunc ac dolor et odio pretium euismod. Cras ligula lectus, commodo id mollis a, euismod eget eros.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="item"></div>
          <div class="item">
            <h2>PURPLE DOTS.</h2>
            <svg>
              <path id="curve" fill="transparent" d="M 75 75 m -50, 0 a 50, 50 0 1, 1 100, 0 a 50, 50 0 1, 1 -100, 0"/>
              <text textLength="310">
                <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
                  *ORGANIC*PRODUCT
                </textPath>
              </text>
            </svg>
            <span class="text-vertical">ORGANIC</span>
            <span class="text-flaveur">Aenean placerat elit quam, sed aliquam mauris rutrum vitae. Vestibulum hendrerit pulvinar iaculis. Sed lectus enim, pulvinar euismod justo eget, sollicitudin vulputate orci.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="item"></div>
          <div class="item">
            <h2>ORANGE VOICE.</h2>
            <svg>
              <path id="curve" fill="transparent" d="M 75 75 m -50, 0 a 50, 50 0 1, 1 100, 0 a 50, 50 0 1, 1 -100, 0"/>
              <text textLength="310">
                <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
                  *ORGANIC*PRODUCT
                </textPath>
              </text>
            </svg>
            <span class="text-vertical">ORGANIC</span>
            <span class="text-flaveur">Vestibulum quis risus erat. Nullam a semper lorem. Integer bibendum, nunc sit amet fermentum elementum.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="item"></div>
          <div class="item">
            <h2>GREEN PATH.</h2>
            <svg>
              <path id="curve" fill="transparent" d="M 75 75 m -50, 0 a 50, 50 0 1, 1 100, 0 a 50, 50 0 1, 1 -100, 0"/>
              <text textLength="310">
                <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
                  *ORGANIC*PRODUCT
                </textPath>
              </text>
            </svg>
            <span class="text-vertical">ORGANIC</span>
            <span class="text-flaveur">Suspendisse vitae lobortis purus. Suspendisse at ligula ut massa fringilla convallis.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="slider">
        <div class="track-full">
          <div class="track-active"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="track-number">01</span>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que tienes que agregar:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Básicamente, sirve para definir qué área de pantalla está disponible al renderizar un documento, cuál es nivel de escalado que puede realizar el usuario, así como si el navegador debe mostrarla con algún zoom inicial.

Comment: Hola @JoseMgz_ux Sí, los tengo agrados en el que tengo yo, pero aun así no me funcionan. Aquí simplemente copié el código sin los links

Comment: Que navegador usas?

Comment: Google Chrome ¿pero aun así los mediaqueries deben salir en cualquiera no?

Comment: Pues sí, acá lo abrí en Google Chrome y Edge pero me funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Prueba agregando `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">` en el encabezado `<head></head>`

Comment: @Mar a mi también me esta funcionando sin problemas, solo adicioné `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` dentro del `<head>` del html, que en este caso 'styles.css' fue que llame a mi archivo css, intenta verificar si importaste de forma correcta tu archivo css

Comment: Listo, con lo de <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"> lo solucione! muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya funcionado, ahí modifique la respuesta a ahora la correcta, dale el gancho de respuesta correcta.